# Is the probability that half the sets are half red, more than half?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $2n$ sets, each of which contains an even number of integers.

Each integer is colored red with probability $1\over2$, independently of the others.

Say that a set is *good* if at least half its elements are red.

Say that a coloring is *good* if at least $n$ out of the $2n$ sets are good

What is the probability $p$ that the random coloring is good?

It is clear that $p\geq {1\over2}$, since for every coloring in which $m$ sets are *not* good, in the opposite coloring at least $m$ sets are good. Therefore, for every not-good coloring, the opposite coloring is good.

Is it always true that $p>{1\over2}$ strictly?

Comment: Can you say anything about what the sizes of these sets are?

Comment: I'm guessing the colorings order doesn't matter ?

Comment: I think that the only time $p=\frac{1}{2}$ is the degenerate case where you let both the size of the sets and the number of sets in the colouring go to infinity. Otherwise it will always be $p>\frac{1}{2}$. This is just my intuitive thinking though... Since I couldn't think of a counter example.

Comment: Let us say a colouring is very good if both it and its opposite colouring are good. Then your question is equivalent to the existence of a very good colouring. Maybe there is some clever way to construct very good colourings but a naive induction argument seems to fail.

Comment: To start:Let $m_i$ the even number integers  of the $2n$ sets, where $i\in \{1,2,3,...n,...,2n\}$

The probability that a set $i$ good is $p_i=0.5^{m_i} \sum\limits_{k=\frac{m_i}2}^{m_i} {m_i\choose k}$

Now we use that ${m_i\choose k}={m_i\choose {m_i-k}}$. Therefore $0.5^{m_i}\sum\limits_{k=\frac{m_i}2+1}^{m_i} {m\choose k}=0.5^{m_i}\sum\limits_{k=\frac{m_i}2-1}^{m_i} {m_i\choose k}=A$

The probabilities add up to one. $2A+0.5^{m_i}  {\frac{m_i}2\choose k}=1$

Consequently $p_i=0.5+0.5^{m_i+1} {\frac{m_i}2\choose k}>0.5$

Comment: Can the sets intersect?

Comment: @Fimpellizieri If they don't intersect then this is obvious because then I can just pick out half of each set to colour red and get a very good colouring (see my comment above).

Comment: I mean $p_i=0.5+0.5^{m_i+1} {m_i\choose \frac{m_i}2}>0.5$

Comment: @T.Gunn Of course.

Comment: @callculus That's interesting. So since all sets are finite, there is a constant $p>0.5$ such that each set is good with probability at least $p$. But can you get from this to the probability that at least half the sets are good?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's always strictly greater.

As T. Gunn says in the comments, it is sufficient to show that there is a *very good* colouring, that is to say a colouring which is good, and remains good after swapping all the colours.

Suppose we have a colouring which is good, but not very good, and let $k$ be the number of sets with a strict majority of red elements. Since these $k$ sets are precisely the sets which will have a strict majority of blue elements after we swap, these are the sets which are not good in the opposite colouring. And the original colouring was not very good, which means $k>n$.

Now pick any red element and colour it blue. Since we have $k>n$ sets with a strict majority of red in the original colouring, we have at least $k>n$ sets which are at least half red in the modified colouring. So the modified colouring is still good.

Finally, choose any good colouring with the smallest possible number of red integers. This must be very good, since if it wasn't we could use the above argument to get a good colouring with fewer red integers, contradicting our choice.

(This argument does not actually require that the number of sets is even, only that every set has even size.)

Comment: Very simple and elegant argument!